# Quartz calendars - including, rather than excluding, dates

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Is there a way in Quartz/Quartz.NET (using the latter but I'm assuming the answer would be the same) to have a type of HolidayCalendar where rather than picking dates to exclude, dates have to be picked to be *included*? So if say 08/02/2012 was added to the calendar, any triggers assigned to this calendar would only execute on this day.

If it's not a built in feature, any ideas on how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to, rather easily, create my own calendar class that implements ICalendar and does exactly what I want - it was simply a case of copying and modifying the HolidayCalendar class in Quartz

Comment: I got the same problem. Do you just modify  `return !(dates.Contains(lookFor));` to `return (dates.Contains(lookFor));` ? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly I've lost my changes to this, but I believe so - the changes were pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post I know, but looking at this, I would disagree that reversing the condition is the best way to go for an "include" calendar - it makes far more sense simply to search for the next value in the list of dates rather than searching the entire list as that's way less efficient.
The list is ordered anyway so makes no sense to trawl the whole collection.

The other problem is the latest Quartz implementation (for .Net at any rate) throws errors if you try and implement a custom calendar outside the library because it can't see certain classes in the base Quartz library, so unless you add the custom calendar in the source itself and then import that you're scuppered.